# facebook API permissions

Tags: iphone, ruby, facebook, facebook-fql, koala

Just starting out with Facebook's API. I have a client that sends me the access_token after logging into to FB on iPhone. I am wondering where I would specify the permissions I need, for example to access email, or user's music data?

Is it via client using `FBSession`, or via `Koala` (ruby gem I use on server side with access_token to get user's info) or in Facebook's app settings page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your user is logging in via an iOS app, you need to request them in the `permissions` parameter of `FBSession`. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSession#permissions

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not a specialist in mobile development, so I cannot provide you with a functional example (or even properly explain how to do this) I have done a bit of browsing in the Facebook API section of the Developers website, and I believe that I have the answer to your questions. This will not only answer where, but it should also give you how, for many different purposes, there are different permissions that you must add, and this page gives you some idea of how to do all of them.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/

Comment: I've seen that page, just not sure where to specify the permissions.